# Angular to SpringBoot - Request permission problem

Tags: spring-boot, http, request, cors, security-filter

I am working on a Spring boot backend app and I did a new Configuration to add a securityFilterChain

Here is my code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvc
public class SecurityConfig {
   private final UserCheckingService userService;
   private final JwtFilter jwtFilter;
   public SecurityConfig(UserCheckingService userService,JwtFilter jwtFilter) {
       this.userService = userService;
       this.jwtFilter = jwtFilter;

   }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .addFilterBefore(
                        this.jwtFilter,
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
                )
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                                .requestMatchers( POST,"/auth").permitAll() // We will authenticate the user
                                .requestMatchers(POST,"/user/create").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(session->
                        session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                )
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.userService);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(this.bCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200"); // Ajoutez vos origines autorisées
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Note that I added CORS Configuration for test purpose and it still doesn't work.

Here is my RestController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class UserController implements DefaultController<User> {
    @Autowired
    private UserCheckingService userService;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private JwtService jwtService;
    @PostMapping("/auth")
    public Map<String, String> connect(@RequestBody User user){

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getLogin().toString(), user.getPassword())
        );
        if(authentication.isAuthenticated()){
            return jwtService.generateToken(user.getLogin().getLogin());
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

And I have a JWT Service but It won't help to solve my problem.

**My problem :**

I tried to connect using /user/auth with Postman (and it worked)
I tried to connect using Angular by setting anyRequest().permitAll() in my securityFilterChain (and it worked)

and then I tried to do the same by setting anyRequest().authenticated()

And it didn't worked.

I am wondering why...
Here is my JS Error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/user/auth' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

```
error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: 'error', …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/user/auth: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok:false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "{localhostURL}"
```

`POST http://localhost:8080/user/auth net::ERR_FAILED 403 (Forbidden)`

It is very weird because when I start debugging, my request goes in doFilterInternal() in my JWTFilter and I am not sure it is supposed to do it...

Also, here is my PostMan :

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/user/auth' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "login": "myLogin",
    "password": "myPwd"
  
}'
```

I think my SpringBoot app wait for me to have a token for my user/auth request but I don't know how to disable it (I thought `.requestMatchers( POST,"/auth").permitAll()` would do the job)
I don't think this is a CORS Policy problem because when I don't restrict to authenticated my requests, it works

Thanks for helping me and sorry for my bad english I did my best ;)